# Filtering / Sorting huge data in Java

Tags: java, sorting, filtering, in-memory-database

Let me first brief about the scenario. The database is Sybase. There are some 2-3 k stored procedures. Stored procedures might return huge data (around million records). There will be a service (servlet / spring controller) which will  call the required procedure and flush the data back to client in xml format.

I need to appy filtering (on multiple column & multiple condition) / sort (based on some dynamic criteria), this I have done.

The issue is, as the data is huge, doing all the filtering / sorting in-memory is not good. I have thought of below options.

**Option 1:**
Once I get the ResultSet object, read some X no. of records, filter it, store it in some file, repeat this process till all the data is read. Then just read the file and flush the data to client.

I need to figure out how do I sort the data in file and how to store objects in file so that the filtering/sorting is fast.

**Option 2:**
Look for some Java API, which takes the data, filters it & sort it based on the given criteria and returns it back as a stream

**Option 3:**
Use in-memory database like hsqldb, h2database, But I think this will overhead instead of helping. I will need to insert data first and then query data and this will also in turn use the file system.

Note I don't want to modify the stored procedures so the option of doing filtering/sorting in database is not an option or might be the last option if nothing else works.

Also if it helps, every record that I read from ResultSet, I store it in a Map, with keys being the column name and this Map is stored in a List, on which I apply the filtering & sorting.

Which option do you think will be good for memory footprint, scalable, performance wise or any other option which will be good for this scenario ?

Thanks

Comment: Modify the stored procedures, or add new ones to call them, save the result in a temp table, then return sublists of the temp table

Comment: Sounds to me like this filtering and sorting is the responsibility of your database. Why not do that there, before you transmit the data? After all that's what databases are good foor. As we say in my country: it sounds like you're tryng to invent the boiled water again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend your **Option 3** but it doesn't need to be an in-memory database; you could use a proper database instead. Any other option would be just a more specific solution to the general problem of sorting huge amounts of data. That is, after all, exactly what a database is for and it does it very well.

If you really believe your Option 3 is not a good solution then you could implement a **sort/merge** solution. Gather your `Map`s as you already do but whenever you reach a limit of records (say 10,000 perhaps) sort them, write them to disk and clear them down from memory.

Once your data is complete you can now open all files you wrote and perform a merge on them.

Comment: hey the other option that you gave is Option 1 :) So you don't see any issue with Option 1

Comment: I suppose it is, yes - but store each batch in a separate file and read ALL of them at once at the end. Each batch is already sorted so all you need to do is merge.

Answer (score 1):

Is hadoop applicable for your problem?

You should filter the data in database itself. You can write aggregation procedure which will execute all other procedures, combine data or filter them However the best option is to modify 2-3 thousands stored procedures so they return only needed data.

Comment: I will checkout aggregation procedure and see if it helps. Regarding modifying procedure, the stored procedures are complex, and the filtering criteria is formed by the user from front end. Modifying stored procedures will be lot of change, as the filtering query needs to be passed and also the existing sql need formed as string, concatenate with the criteria string passed and execute.

Comment: As mentioned in comment below your question: you can use temporary tables to hold result and filter them.

Comment: The database is Sybase. Yes I will look into aggregation procedure / temp table.